# Add random number to batch file that generates temp passwords

Tags: batch-file, random, digit

I would be very grateful if some one could help me fix my script, I want to add a 4 digit random number to the end of a string, in essence it is a script that reads a csv file for an email address then creates a powershell file for me to run but the part im having issues with is the random 4 digit number appended to the password string, please see below, if I run the script now it runs without errors but no 4 digit random number appended, can anyone help im sure its something small im missing thanks

Spud

---

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%j in ('type "Input.csv"') do (
set /A RND=%RANDOM% %% 8889 + 1111
echo.Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName %%j -StrongPasswordRequired $false
echo.Set-MsolUserPassword -userPrincipalName %%j -NewPassword "TTech%RND%*" -ForceChangePassword   $false
echo.Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName %%j -PasswordNeverExpires $true
echo.   
) >> "Output.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `%var%` to `!var!` to access the dynamic value of a variable with `delayedexpansion` in effect.

```
set /A RND=!RANDOM! %% 8889 + 1111
```

would set your variable `RND` to 1111..9999

```
echo.Set-MsolUserPassword -userPrincipalName %%j -NewPassword "TTech!RND!*" -ForceChangePassword   $false
```

would then append the resultant value to `TTech`

Alternatively, try

```
set RND=000!RANDOM!
...
echo.Set-MsolUserPassword -userPrincipalName %%j -NewPassword "TTech!RND:~-4!*" -ForceChangePassword   $false
```

which would construct a string `000`+`0`..`32767` and then use the last 4 characters after `TTech` so you'd get leading-zero-filled 4-digit numerics.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your random number:

```
Set max=9999
Set min=1000
Set /A rand=%random% %% (max - min + 1)+ min
Echo %rand%
```

Keep in mind, inside of a for loop, you'll need to use delayedexpansion and escape the parenthesis.

```
 Set max=9999
 Set min=1000

 for /l %%a in (1,1,10) do (
 Set /A rand=!random! %% ^( max - min + 1 ^) + min
 Echo.!rand!
 )
 exit /b
```

Based on Magoo's answer, you know the issue was with using delayed variable syntax instead of standard parens. I wrapped up his answer and mine into a couple of little functions that are easily reusable.

```
call :RandomRange 1000 9999 ret
Echo %ret%

call :RandomRange2 ret
echo %ret%
exit /b

:RandomRange min max ret
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set /A rand=!random! %% (%2 - %1 + 1) + %1
endlocal & set %3=%rand%
exit /b

:RandomRange2 ret
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set rnd=000!random!
set rnd=!rnd:~-4!
endlocal & set %1=%rnd%
exit /b
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This does not address the question.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a random 4 digit number:

```
set num=%random%%random%%random%%random%
set num=%num:~-4%
```

Or with delayed expansion enabled inside a loop:

```
set num=!random!!random!!random!!random!
set num=!num:~-4!
```